# Работа с многомерными массивами. Фильтрация данных

Tags: javascript, массивы, reactjs, диаграммы

Есть кто работал с многомерным массивом?

```
const countries = [
  ['Income', 'Life Expectancy', 'Population', 'Country', 'Year'],
  [815, 34.05, 351014, 'Australia', 1800],
  [1314, 39, 645526, 'Canada', 1800],
  [985, 32, 321675013, 'China', 1800],
  [864, 32.2, 345043, 'Cuba', 1800],
  [1244, 36.5731262, 977662, 'Finland', 1800],
  [1803, 33.96717024, 29355111, 'France', 1800],
  [1639, 38.37, 22886919, 'Germany', 1800],
];
```

По типу такого
Мне по задаче нужно выделить: Country, Year, Population
Для вывода в инфографику
Можете подсказать какие методы нужно использовать или решение)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Методы массивов](https://learn.javascript.ru/array-methods)

Answer (score 0):

Я сделал вот так. Наверное это один из самых память-затратных реализации :) [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/azamat96/j064h9vb/35/)

Кратко, принимаю названия столбцов и получаю индексы этих столбцов, и перебираю значения многомерного массива по полученным индексам

```
function getColumns(...args) {
    const indexes = args.reduce((indexes, column) => {
        const i = countries[0].indexOf(column)
        if ( i >= 0) {
            return (indexes.push(i), indexes)
        } 
        return indexes
    }, [])
    
    if (!indexes.length) { 
        return [] 
    }
    
    return countries.map((row) => {
            return indexes.reduce((newRow, i) => {
                return (newRow.push(row[i]), newRow), [])
            }
    })
}

console.log(getColumns('Population', 'Country', 'Income'))
```